# # in the CSV header

Tags: csv, etl

When validating a csv file, generated through some ETL tool, we used to highlight an issue of # present in the beginning of the header.
Just want to know what impact does it have if a csv file has a # in the beginning of the haeder.

Comment: Bear in mind that CSV can be very loosely defined. It's not some strict file format with official definitions. All that you're really guaranteed is that it's some kind of file with separators. How any individual application *interprets* the contents of any such file is only application defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has no impact directly to the CSV (except for the `#` being there). It depends on what you are using to read the CSV.

Usually, whatever is in the first cell of the header will now be interpreted as `#$HEADER_CELL` instead of just `$HEADER_CELL`.